# why the meilisearch index disappear

Tags: meilisearch

I have already add the `project_id` index in meilisearch https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch, but after some peroiod of time. The meilisearch `project_id` disappears automatically. and the search will show error:

```
2023-12-04T12:08:57.480187894+00:00 ERROR texhub_server::service::project::project_service - search failed,Meilisearch invalid_request: invalid_search_filter: Attribute `project_id` is not filterable. Available filterable attributes are: `name`.
1:11 project_id = 287ea73d1c78463298e9e5b267cab87f. https://docs.meilisearch.com/errors#invalid_search_filter, params: SearchProjParams { project_id: "287ea73d1c78463298e9e5b267cab87f", keyword: "address" }
```

when did the index disappeared? I have already specify the storage folder and bound with the NFS in kubernetes pod. how to handle the file are exists but the index are disappeared?